# Factory object creating objects that need other objects

Tags: php, design-patterns, dependency-injection, factory-pattern, solid-principles

I need a factory object able to create several objects but in injecting other objects in them.
For example:

```
class MyFactory
{
  public function createObjectA() {
    return new ObjectA(new ObjectANeededObject1(), new ObjectANeededObject1());
  }

  public function createObjectB() {
    return new ObjectB(new ObjectBNeededObject1(), new ObjectBNeededObject1());
  }
}
```

Should my factory also instantiate the required object (considering my factory is allowed to create any object)?
Should I pass them by injection into my factory constructor (but the constructor will contain many many many parameters)?
Should I pass them as parameter into my factory method (but the factory client will then know how the object to create should be created and it's not its responsibility to know it)?
Should my factory create object builders (able to create my objects and their required objects) instead of my object directly?

What do you recommand?

Thank you,

Ben

Comment: Methings 'tis time you started reading about [Dependency Injection Containers](http://www.phptherightway.com/#containers) (DIC)

Comment: Thank you Mark. If I understand well, a container will help us to create my different objects ObjectXNeddedObjectY. But if I'm not wrong it's the same problem, I read that I shouldn't give my container to all objects but simply pass the objects created by the container. So should I pass all my objects ObjectXNeddedObjectY (created by my container) to my factory ?

Comment: The DIC should return a collection of objects specific to the class that is to be instantiated, and the factory can then use reflection to instantiate that class with the collection using a call like `http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php`

Comment: Didn't really understand what you want to do with reflection but do you think my factory should contain the DI container ?

Comment: Take a look at how DI containers like [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/), or [Aura.Di](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Di), or [Dice](https://r.je/dice.html) or [Orno\Di](https://github.com/orno/di) actually work... they could really simplify things for you

Comment: Do you think I should pass the container to my factory ? On the PHP-DI website, they say: "Do not use this everywhere because this makes your code dependent on the container. This is an antipattern to dependency injection (it is like the service locator pattern: dependency fetching rather than injection)."

Comment: The factory should have access to the container, certainly; but I wouldn't inject the container into the factory, I'd have the factory able to access the container as a service

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Factory` should not know how to instanciate an object from class `ObjectBNeededObject1`, because if the constructor changes, you will have to go back also to the class `Factory` and do the necessary job to avoid a regression

**UPDATED**

```
class MyFactory
{
  public static function createObjectA($object1, $object2) {
    return new ObjectA($object1, $object2);
  }

  public static function createObjectB($object1, $object2) {
    return new ObjectB($object1, $object2);
  }
}

$objectA = MyFactory->createObjectA(new ObjectANeededObject1(), new ObjectANeededObject1());
$objectB = MyFactory->createObjectB(new ObjectANeededObject1(), new ObjectANeededObject1());
```

Comment: Thank you Halayem. But I don't like that the client of the factory has to know which objects the factory needs in order to create the wished object. For example if the client is a class Workflow that needs to work with several kinds of "workflow step", if one of these steps requires for example a HttpRequest object, so my workflow object will contain both the factory able to create the steps and the HttpRequest.

Comment: What you are suggesting makes no sense and defeats the purpose of a factory... "because if the constructor changes, you will ahve to go back also to the..." if you think about it, that's actually an argument against letting the client instanciate the concrete classes directly.